# Accessing and setting state in an react/flux application

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'm working on a react app with a flux implementation.

I have a store which is bound to a component and in the `ctor` I set some default (blank) state values. In `componentWillMount` I populate the state by firing some actions which update the store data. 
The store emits a change and the component handles that change by putting bits of the store data into state.

In my `render` method, I'm wanting the render to depend on the state data.

At the moment I have a couple of issues.

1. If in my `render` method I do something like this.state.MyThing.AProperty then the render method is called too early when MyThing hasn't been populated yet. This seems to occur in a lot of places where I want a render to use state data. Is there a sensible guard against this or am I doing this wrong?
2. I'm using a store to emit a change, and handling that change by getting data from the store and setting it to the `state` of the component. My thinking here is that if I set it as state then the component will know to re-render when the state changes. Is this correct? or should I be getting the data from the store in the emit handler and using it directly? or setting it to a local var in the component?
   The reason I ask is that I seem to encounter issues with `setState` calls not being immediate and wanting to use state as soon as I set it. With this in mind it seems like I might be doing it wrong.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you use conditionals in your render, then you can guard against unpopulated data being rendered.

```
<div>
  {typeof this.state.myThing == 'object' ?
    <strong>this.state.myThing.aProperty</strong> :
    <span>Nothing to see here</span>}
</div>
```

And with regards to your second question, yeah. That's totally fine and it's the expected way to work with Flux. You can even take inspiration from Redux & Co and make [higher order components that map store state to props](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

```
function connect(store, mapStateToProps, Component) {
  return React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      const state = store.getState();
      return { state };
    },
    componentWillMount() {
      store.listen(state => this.setState({ state }));
    },
    render() {
      const stateProps = mapStateToProps(this.state);
      const passedProps = this.props;
      const props = Object.assign({}, stateProps, passedProps);
      return <Component {...props} />;
    }
  });
}
```

This pattern allows you to take an existing component and wrap it in a *container* that will re-render whenever the store changes, then use the `mapStateToProps` function to work out which props to pass down to your original component.

```
const MyStore = { ... };

const MyComponent = React.createClass( ... );

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { foo: state.bar.foo };
}

export default connect(MyStore, mapStateToProps, MyComponent);
```

`setState` is an asychronous method as it needs to be batched to keep React apps from being delaying repaints when they trigger lots of updates. You can reliably wait for the state to change by passing a callback as the second argument.

```
this.setState({ foo: 'bar' }, () => this.state.foo);
```

Comment: I did think the conditional approach for each component was a bit verbose, but I guess there isn't a super nice way to avoid it.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan either, but you can make it look nicer by moving the conditional out to a component method/helper function and instead returing from a top-level `if` statement.